# Generate new date based on week+month of actual year

Tags: php

Im developing a calendar with fixeds intervals.
But there are 2 vacations on it, mid year and end year.
Mid year vacation starts on 3° Monday of July of that actual year, and
end year vacation starts on penultimate Monday of December of that actual year.

Is there any way I can get or generate this vacation dates?

The closest I found was something like this

`$mid_vacation= date('w',strtotime($my_date.'Monday last week'));`

Comment: Can you please provide some details on your desired results? However, you can use some fairly liberal ordinal dates with things like `date_create('fourth thursday of november + 1 day')` for Black Friday https://3v4l.org/FXn3d. Or `last monday of may` for memorial day. Which will use the current date object year as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more ways, but the terms to follow all work as desired.  I don't find instantiating a date class object to be as attractive because you don't need any of the extra functionality after generating the string.  For this reason, I recommend `strtotime()` with `date()`.  You are free to select which ever expression you wish depending on "readability", "brevity", or whatever criteria.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XKGfZ))

```
echo "3rd Monday of July: " , date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first Monday of July +2 weeks"));
echo "\n";
echo "3rd Monday of July: " , date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 weeks first Monday of July"));
echo "\n";
echo "3rd Monday of July: " , date("Y-m-d", strtotime("third Monday of July"));

echo "\n---\n";

echo "Penultimate / Second last Monday in December: " , date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Monday of December this year -1 week"));
echo "\n";
echo "Penultimate / Second last Monday in December: " , date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week last Monday of December"));
```

Output:

```
3rd Monday of July: 2019-07-15
3rd Monday of July: 2019-07-15
3rd Monday of July: 2019-07-15
---
Penultimate / Second last Monday in December: 2019-12-23
Penultimate / Second last Monday in December: 2019-12-23
```

*December seems to require `this year` in the first expression; @fyrye tells us why...

> The issue with `December` is due to the usage of `last|first dayname of` when using `+` or `-` since it assumes you are specifying a timezone. See the notes on [Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). You can use `-7 days last Monday of December` instead https://3v4l.org/KBrEs0
>   – [fyrye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144627/fyrye)

Comment: the issue with December is due to the usage of `last|first dayname of` when using + or - since it assumes you are specifying a timezone, See the notes on [*Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). You can use `-7 days last Monday of December` instead https://3v4l.org/KBrEs0

Answer (score -1):

Check DateTime class

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$test = new DateTime('2019-07-01');
echo $test->modify('first monday')->format('Y-m-d');

$test = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
echo $test->modify('last monday of this month')->format('Y-m-d');
```